# Spring Integration TCP Listen For Second Response On Same Socket

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration

I have a spring boot project and I'm using Spring Integration to TCP communications. I'm sending the request to server and server returns 06 as ACK firstly. After a few seconds, the actual response is coming from server. Sometimes ACK and actual response comes together but mostly they don't.
In spring integration how can I handle this? What should I do to wait actual response after ACK reveived? Or how can I read the actual response? How can I rach it?

This is my TCP configuration:

```
<bean id="messageSerializer"
      class="MyCustomByteArraySerializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpClientFactory"
                               type="client"
                               host="${host}"
                               port="${port}"
                               so-keep-alive="true"
                               single-use="false"
                               using-nio="true"
                               serializer="messageSerializer"
                               deserializer="messageSerializer"/>

<ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outboundGateway"
                         connection-factory="tcpClientFactory"
                         request-channel="toTcpAdapterChannel"
                         reply-channel="fromTcpAdapterChannel"
                         auto-startup="true"
                         request-timeout="90000"
                         remote-timeout="90000"
                         reply-timeout="90000"/>
```

EDIT: My deserializer like this:

```
@Override
    public byte[] deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        int length = inputStream.available();
        logger.info("Available length of inputStream is: {}", length);
        byte[] incomingArray = new byte[length];
        this.read(inputStream, incomingArray, false);
        if (length == 1) {
            logger.info("Length is 1. Incoming byte: {}", HexUtils.toHexString(incomingArray));
            return null;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message DUMP-1! " + HexUtils.toHexString(incomingArray));
            incomingArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(incomingArray, 1, length - 1);
        }
        return incomingArray;

    }
```

EDIT 2: Taking code to while loop solved my problem.

```
@Override
    public byte[] deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        boolean allMessageRead = false;
        byte[] incomingArray = new byte[0];
        while (!allMessageRead) {
            int length = inputStream.available();
            incomingArray = new byte[length];
            this.read(inputStream, incomingArray, false);
            if (length == 1) {
                logger.info("Available length of inputStream is: {}", length);
                logger.info("Length is 1. Incoming byte: {}", HexUtils.toHexString(incomingArray));
                return null;
            } else if (length > 1) {
                System.out.println("Message DUMP-1! " + HexUtils.toHexString(incomingArray));
                incomingArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(incomingArray, 1, length - 3);
                allMessageRead = true;
            }
        }


        return incomingArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom deserializer and discard the part you are not interested in.

Comment: Hi Gary. I already have a custom deserializer and when one 1 byte response comes, I ignore it with returning null in deserialize method. I edited my question and added my deserialize method.

Comment: Don't return `null`, just add a while loop in `deserialize` until you get all the bytes you expect - that's what all the standard deserializers do. TCP is a stream; there is no guarantee that the input won't be broken into packets.

Comment: Thank you Gary. I tried with your comment and I can get the actual response after the ACK.